Is it possible to simulate signal propagation in a 3D environment and visualize a coverage map in Blender?
Currently, I have created a 3D model of a building in Blender. My goal is to simulate signal propagation between transmitters and receivers using 3D ray tracing. I expect to obtain a 3D output with ray traces and a coverage map indicating the power levels received by the receivers.
I have already placed antennas in the 3D environment and I would like to know if it is possible to achieve this in Blender.
Any responses and suggestions are welcome.
Thank you in advance.

Here is an example of what I want to do. A heatmap that allows visualization of the received signal strength in the 3D building. I am asking if this can be done in Blender.

is that [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/gyAs56Iz.gif what you want?

Yes, that could interest me, but by displaying the received power level in dB.

then i would recommend providing a formula based on the distance which results the power level in db. And did you try anything or just modeled the antennas? Because it sounds a bit like "i am searching for someone who does my work".

Yes, I have already modeled a 3D building and also placed antennas that I consider as transmitters. I have created a network and I want to simulate the coverage by evaluating the power level throughout the building. I am wondering if there are any add-ons in Blender to do this or if it can be done with the Cycles render engine?

Hello, the answer is yes but you won't be able to do it with native blender tools, and AFAIK there is no publicly available addon to do that. You'll have to code your own addon or build a custom blender version to add such functionality.

Ok, but is it possible to use ray tracing in Blender to simulate wave (or light) propagation while taking into account the building's obstacles (walls, partitions, etc.) in order to obtain reflections?

Sure, Cycles is physically based so you just have to put a light source somewhere and the illumination will give a pretty good approximation of where the light bounces. You can then bake the resulting map to a texture to get illumination values

Doesn't this require a Python script? I already have a script that simulates the RSSI from the antennas placed in the building. Given that ray tracing can be used as a propagation model, would it be possible to use Cycles' ray tracing in my code to take into account the various obstacles in the building (physical properties of materials)?
